# How to create predicate to filter entities on field with Transformable type?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I simply have entity `Service` with property `students`. That field is of `Transformable` type defined in `.xcdatamodelm`.

Within code my property is defined as `[String]`:

```
@NSManaged var students: [String]
```

Now I need to filter all services where students is not empty.

When I do it like this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "students.@count != 0")
let services = Service.mr_findAll(with: predicate) as! [Service]
```

But here an error arise:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported function expression count:(students)'

Comment: What does `@count` mean?

Comment: Number of elements in an array.

Comment: Yes. I was just wondering why it isn't simply "students.count"

Comment: Think `@count` is applicable for relationships only.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to fetch with a predicate by your custom types since `Transformable` field can hold any data. So all your requests will use transient properties but "You cannot fetch using a predicate based on transient properties (although you can use transient properties to filter in memory yourself)." from  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspropertydescription.

The only way to filter your array in memory:

```swift
let filtered = allServices.filter { $0.students.count > 0 }
```